# Can we call method using the reference of the class

Tags: java, class, jsp

I just started to learn java and i found out that, to call a method of normal class  we need object but for static class we do not need any object to call we can use class reference to do that. But while coding I came across some code which really confused me. The code is.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
String result = actionInvocation.invoke();
```

Here my doubt is in the 3rd line we have a reference actionInvocation for a class ActionInvocation and we have not used any new keyword and now check the 4th line we used actionInvocation to access the methos invoke(). How is this possible without using new keyword? I also checked that ActionInvocation is abstract interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly fine code. The `ActionInvocation` instance is created elsewhere and passed to the `intercept(...)` method. In fact `ActionInvocation actionInvocation` is just a reference to an object of a class that extends or implements `ActionInvocation`, i.e. the actual class of that object could be a subclass/implementation of `ActionInvocation`.

The concept behind this is called polymorphism: an object of a certain class is also an object of its superclasses and/or might be referenced through implemented interfaces.

An example:

Suppose you have an object like this:

```
Integer someInt = new Integer(1);
```

You could pass `someInt` as a parameter to the following methods:

```
void doSomething( Integer i) { ... }
void doSomething( Number n) { ... }} //because Integer extends Number
void doSomething( Object o) { ... } //because all objects extend Object
void doSomething( Comparable c) { ...} //because Integer implements Comparable (note that I left out generics here for simplicity)
```

Note that you could also pass `null` as an object, as the others already stated, but in your case you should be safe to assume that `actionInvocation` is never null (this is most likely documented in the API docs).

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword is only used to construct an object. Once it has been created, it can be passed around between methods, other classes, and other places where an object may be stored or transmitted.

You are making a method of `MyInterceptor` that accepts an `ActionInvocation` object. This object can either be passed as null, or would have been created elsewhere. You can perform a not-null check (via `actionInvocation!=null`) to ensure that you're indeed passed an object.

Also, you should remember that you yourself can create objects without using `new` in your class. There are such ways called factories, where you call a static method such as `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(` and that *internally* uses the `new` keyword to create an instance of ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

`actionInvocation` is initialized(with `new`) in another place of the program.

Comment: this is struts2 interceptor program, so you mean to say is actionInvocation is initialized in interceptor related program?

Comment: It is somehow created else where.Maybe by struts2.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation)
```

To call this method any where in your program,

you need to have a **created object** of type `ActionInvocation`, then and then only you can call that method.

Once you pass to that,The story inside is usual.

In short,

That object created before calling this method and coming  here to do the stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a little more understanding of how inheritance and interfaces work to understand this. But the overall logic here is that the method is assuming that object of type ActionInvocation is already instantiated, which might not be the case. Anyways you can look at the calling code for method `intercept` where an object being passed here must have been instantiated by using new.

By the way ActionInvocation is interface so any "subclass" of this interface can call this method. Have a look at the inheritance terminology to understand what that means.